# Maven build: Tomcat server doesn't start

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat

I am new to Maven and trying to setup a web project using Maven. I have setup the project in Eclipse and I am using Tomcat 7.0.53. In run configuration for Maven build and I have set `tomcat:run` in `Goals`. 
When I run this configuration, following log is seen in the Eclipse console:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Chat sample using the Spring MVC Servlet-based async support 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> tomcat-maven-plugin:1.1:run (default-cli) > compile @ spring-mvc-chat >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) @ spring-mvc-chat ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ spring-mvc-chat ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< tomcat-maven-plugin:1.1:run (default-cli) < compile @ spring-mvc-chat <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- tomcat-maven-plugin:1.1:run (default-cli) @ spring-mvc-chat ---
[INFO] Running war on http://localhost:8080/spring-mvc-chat
[INFO] Using existing Tomcat server configuration at D:\Workspace\spring-mvc-chat-master\target\tomcat
Jul 21, 2014 11:26:44 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Embedded start
INFO: Starting tomcat server
Jul 21, 2014 11:26:45 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.29
Jul 21, 2014 11:26:45 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Jul 21, 2014 11:26:45 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
```

Nothing happens after this. There is no info of server startup and hence the project can't run at all. 
Is any step is being missed here? Or this IS the correct behaviour?

Comment: "I am using Tomcat 7.0.53" -> INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.29. There is something horribly wrong alright, if you are already not starting the Tomcat version you think you are starting.

Comment: After changing to `mvn tomcat7:run`, the console stuck at:
`Jul 21, 2014 1:15:26 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]`

Comment: have you checked http://localhost:8080/spring-mvc-chat in your browser? because this output seems ok for me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For Tomcat 7 use `mvn tomcat7:run` Ref: [Maven Tomcat 7](http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.0/tomcat7-maven-plugin/)

Comment: I had exactly same issue where maven was picking up apache 6.0.29 tomcat and not 7. Because of this webservlets were not loading. Thanks...